# Browse folders and add their files to a list with qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

Hello Great community of SO!

I have created a GUI application with qt and I added a QTreeWidget and a 2 buttons (add and delete) in my main window.

Is it possible to find examples of code in order to learn how to add and delete files to this QTreeWidget ?

- I would like to display their size, name and location into the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For directory browsing try [QDir](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdir.html).
To create and remove files use [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfile.html).
Quite a lot of examples and tutorials can be found here [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/).
Just select your release.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the demos that come bundled with Qt itself?
I can tell you of two examples:

1. In QtAssistant, go to Qt Reference Documentation->Overviews->View Classes and you have your example.
2. More elaborate: In QtAssistant, go to: Qt Reference Documentation->Tutorials and Examples: Under XQuery,XPath you have File System Example.

Adding file can be as simple as opening a new file (taking the filename from user) and closing it (I don't know what exactly you want here - some equivalent of "touch" command?).

For deleting, you can call: bool QDir::remove ( const QString & fileName )